# SCRIPT87: Invalid argument

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a jquery function that works in all browser, but not in ie7 and ie9 in compatibily mode.
The problem is in this function:

```
$('.non-attivo').live('click',function(){
    clearInterval(start_slide);
    n_btn = "";
    for(var i=1;i<$(this).attr('id').length; i++)
        n_btn += $(this).attr('id')[i] + "";
    slide_pos = parseInt(n_btn, 10);
    var margin_slider = slide_pos * 780;
    $('#immagini').animate({ marginLeft: "-" + margin_slider + "px"}, 500 );
    $('.attivo').attr('class', 'non-attivo');
    $(this).attr('class', 'attivo');
    start_slide = setInterval(rotate, 4000);
});
```

The error is:

> SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
>
> jquery.min.js, line 4 character 23894

How can I fix it?

Comment: how can you be sure that the issue is in this function?

Comment: because the others works fine. I also tried to comment the other code and I get the same error

Comment: Mostlikely the way you determine `margin_slider` is causing the issue. It must be returning a `NaN` in `parseInt`. Try `alert(margin_slider)` before `.animate` and see what it returns. Its very hard to conclude with the limited information.

Comment: And which line is triggering the error? Have a look at the call stack.

Comment: Yes the problem is that margin_slider is Nan. How can i get an integer?

Comment: @pindol That depends on what you are iterating.. Debug more to see what is getting returned for `n_btn` and what is expected. If `n_btn` returns a numeric string or any string beginning with number should return you are number.. but seems like it doesn't.

Comment: n_btn returns NaN. I have to take a number from an id composed by a letter followed by a number (b12, a43, ..)

Comment: Try using `.charAt(i)` instead `[i]`. Also you can `var thisId = this.id` and then use the var instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: Please post on how you solved it. Posted the above comments as answer. Good luck. If the issue was different, then please post that as an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Mostlikely the way you determine `margin_slider` is causing the issue. It must be returning a `NaN` in `parseInt`.

Try `alert(margin_slider)` before `.animate` and see what it returns.

Also It depends on what you are iterating.. Debug more to see what is getting returned for `n_btn` and what is expected. If `n_btn` returns a numeric string or any string beginning with number should return you are number.. but seems like it doesn't.

Try using `.charAt(i)` instead `$(this).attr('id')[i]`. And you can `var thisId = this.id` and then use the var instead of `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a few days ago.

In case anyone else also stumbles upon this, the issue was that I was using HTML button elements which IE9- doesn't seem to know how to handle. Adding a HTML shim solved the problem.