# jQuery range slider gives "Invalid Argument" in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, slider

For some reason IE8 decided to give the "invalid argument" for this [page](http://www.posterlion.com/#/search/?searchKeyword=scarface&priceFrom=0) when running the following code

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    step:5,
    max: 50,
    values: [ $('#fro').val(), $('#to').val() ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#fro" ).val(ui.values[0]);
        $( "#to" ).val(ui.values[1]);
        $( "#asdf" ).html( window.currencySymbol + ui.values[0] + " - " + window.currencySymbol + ui.values[1]);    
    },
    stop:function( event, ui ) {
        $.address.parameter('priceFrom', ui.values[0]);
        $.address.parameter('priceTo', ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

I can't find any info about why. What's wrong with it? In all the other browsers there's no problem as usual. Only IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the browser mode and document mode to IE9/IE9 standarts and check if still dont work (press F12 in IE) if works its only available to IE9+ if not can be a bug or sometthing in IE check console log, and do brealpoints to see what is going on

Comment: I know that. The error only persists in IE8. With ie9 there's no problem. The problem is only the above given code and it refers to jquery.min.js

Comment: maybe there is some html5 component and IE8 dont support it

Comment: It's only the slider thing. 'SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 75705' refers to some styling. The other slider works.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236280/ie-invalid-argument-with-jquery , and this too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390252/script87-invalid-argument

Comment: I really have no idea what the problem is. It's just in IE8. I'm thinking of just disabling it in that browser. I don't want to spend too much time for something that is outdated and declining anyway. Too many IE problems the last few days.